# Win32com Module Problems

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I want to convert .xls to .xlsx, so I use win32com module

this is my code:

```py
import os
import win32com.client as win32
address = address = os.getcwd()

fname = address + "\\Bundles.xls"
fname2 = address + "\\searchresults.xls"
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel2 = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fname)
wb5 = excel.Workbooks.Open(fname2)

wb.SaveAs(fname+"x", FileFormat = 51)
wb5.SaveAs(fname2+"x", FileFormat = 51)    #FileFormat = 51 is for .xlsx extension
wb.Close()
wb5.Close()                               #FileFormat = 56 is for .xls extension
excel.Application.Quit()
excel2.Application.Quit()
print('File .xls convert .xlsx successful!!')
```

then I got the error, here it is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/shenshuaic/Desktop/SFP Program/win32test.py", line 7, in <module>
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
  File "C:\Users\shenshuaic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 527, in EnsureDispatch
    disp = win32com.client.Dispatch(prog_id)
  File "C:\Users\shenshuaic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 96, in Dispatch
    return __WrapDispatch(dispatch, userName, resultCLSID, typeinfo, clsctx=clsctx)
  File "C:\Users\shenshuaic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 37, in __WrapDispatch
    klass = gencache.GetClassForCLSID(resultCLSID)
  File "C:\Users\shenshuaic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 183, in GetClassForCLSID
    mod = GetModuleForCLSID(clsid)
  File "C:\Users\shenshuaic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 226, in GetModuleForCLSID
    mod = GetModuleForTypelib(typelibCLSID, lcid, major, minor)
  File "C:\Users\shenshuaic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 266, in GetModuleForTypelib
    AddModuleToCache(typelibCLSID, lcid, major, minor)
  File "C:\Users\shenshuaic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\win32com\client\gencache.py", line 552, in AddModuleToCache
    dict = mod.CLSIDToClassMap
AttributeError: module 'win32com.gen_py.00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9' has no attribute 'CLSIDToClassMap'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're running into a bug which happens when you use `early binding` with `win32com`. My recommendation is if you can use `late binding` as you won't receive the error. If you do need to use `early binding` then you can need to delete the auto-generated python code from `win32com`. If you go to this location on your system:

- `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py`

You'll see some folders in there, where each folder represents the version of python that code was generated for. For example, if you see `3.7` that means `python 3.7`. Regardless of which one you see go inside and you should see a bunch of different python files. Where each file represents a different object that you've specified `early binding` for.
All you need to do is just delete the `3.7` folder or whatever it is and re-run your code. That fixes the issue 90% of the time.

Now with your code, I would recommend you modify it a little since you really do not need to have two instances of Excel opened at the same time.

```py
import os
import win32com.client as win32

address = address = os.getcwd()

file_name_1 = address + "\\Bundles.xls"
file_name_2 = address + "\\searchresults.xls"

new_file_name_1 = file_name_1 + "_converted"
new_file_name_2 = file_name_2 + "_converted"

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

file_1 = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_name_1)
file_2 = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_name_2)

file_1.SaveAs(new_file_name_1, FileFormat = 51)
file_2.SaveAs(new_file_name_2, FileFormat = 51)   

file_1.Close()
file_2.Close()

excel.Application.Quit()

print('File .xls convert .xlsx successfully!!')
```